# Relative paths VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to go from absolute to relative paths.

My macro is in folder \models\vba

and this macro uses sheets from the folders \models\Main ,and \models\aear as below

```
 Set Main = Workbooks.Open("D:\Shared\Models\Main\Main 2017.xlsx")
```

I've been shopping around already, and it seems its easiest to use

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

What's the best way to go back one directory, and then enter the Macro map.?

Comment: How is the `D:\Shared` directory related to the location of the workbook file?

Comment: Is your project comprised of a single `*.xlsx`/`*.xls` workbook file, or multiple files? How is your "macro in a folder"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct relative paths the usual way but you need always to append them to `ThisWorkbook.Path`.

```
Set Main = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\..\Main\Main 2017.xlsx")
```

Each `..` goes one step up in the folder tree.

You can eventualy encapsulate this by building your own function that constructs the absolute path from your relative path

```
Function RelToAbs(RelPath as string) as string
    RelToAbs = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & RelPath
End function

Set Main = Workbooks.Open(RelToAbs("..\Main\Main 2017.xlsx"))
```

Comment: post the path of your start folder and post the path of your target folder.

Comment: start folder D:\Shared\Models\vba  ___ target folders D:\Shared\Models\Main D:\Shared\Models\aear

Comment: @Ken : if ThisWorkbook.Path is `D:\Shared\Models\vba`, `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\.."` is `D:\Shared\Models`... and `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\..\Main` is `D:\Shared\Models\Main`

Comment: Wait it, actually did work, i messed up the addressing myself for a sec. @ ASH, Correct. i messed up. Thanks mate !